# RemoteException sending setActive(false) notification - Random Activity closing

Tags: android, android-activity

I'm developing a simple Android Game app. During my main activity (the activity used to play) , when a condition is verified, after 1/2 second, I want to stop the current activity and restart it. The Game sometimes works well BUT often, randomly, it crashes "without errors" [it doesn't re-start the activity but it closes the view returning to the Game Menu Activity (the activity used for Menu, Options, etc. ...)].

The following is the piece of code when the issue happens:

```
if(scoreManager.isEndGame()){
                    final Handler mHandler = new Handler();
                    Runnable mUpdateTimeTask = new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            long remainingTime = scoreManager.getSecondsUntilFinished();
                            scoreManager.setRemainingTime(remainingTime*1000);
                            finish();
                            startActivity(getIntent());
                        }

                    };
                    mHandler.postDelayed(mUpdateTimeTask, 500);
                }
```

**scoreManager** contains a CountDownTimer which is istantiated with remainingTime at each restarting (it is instantiated on onCreate()).

On LogCat I read:

> InputMethodManagerService : Got RemoteException sending
>   setActive(false) notification to pid 18494 uid 10062
>
> I/ActivityManager : Displayed com.myproject.activities/.MenuActivity:
>   +774ms (total +3s697ms)

Basically often the activity is destroyed and it is not restarted.
No exception is thrown. I'm having this problem testing on my "HTC Desire".

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLVED!!!

Finally I've found the problem, it was on "onCreate" method of the main activity.
Trying to set a background image randomly, sometimes the selected image  had a resolution too large 1024x768 or bigger (R.drawable.background_3 and R.drawable.background_5) and for this reason the main activity was interrupted and returned to MenuActivity. I solved setting the resolution of all backgrounds images to 640x480.

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    try{
       //stuff...

       //set background
       LinearLayout linLay = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainLayout);
      linLay.setBackgroundResource(getBackgroundCode(new Random().nextInt(12)));

       //other stuff...
    }catch(Exception e){
        Log.e("MainPlayActivity", "onCreate() - Error during cretion. Exception: "+e.getMessage(), e);
    }
}



private int getBackgroundCode(int n){

    int result=0;

    switch (n){
    case 0:
        result = R.drawable.background_0;
        break;
    case 1:
        result = R.drawable.background_1;
        break;
    case 2: 
        result = R.drawable.background_2;
        break;
    case 3: 
        result = R.drawable.background_3;
        break;
    case 4: 
        result = R.drawable.background_4;
        break;
    case 5: 
        result = R.drawable.background_5;
        break;
    case 6: 
        result = R.drawable.background_6;
        break;
    case 7: 
        result = R.drawable.background_7;
        break;
    case 8: 
        result = R.drawable.background_8;
        break;
    case 9: 
        result = R.drawable.background_9;
        break;
    case 10: 
        result = R.drawable.background_10;
        break;
    case 11: 
        result = R.drawable.background_11;
        break;
    default :
        result = R.drawable.background_0;
    }
    return result;
}
```